# Can you help me solve this inequality $\left|\frac{2}{x-4}\right| >1$

Tags: inequality

Please help me with this inequality I keep getting answer as $(-\infty , 6)\cup (2, \infty)$  which of course is incorrect

Comment: When inequalities are going wrong for me, I like to do some sanity tests. Try the points that I'm getting in the original inequality. If they don't work, something has gone wrong, and I go back through my working and try the points at various places in my working. I then try to isolate the exact line of working where my test points stop working. That's when the problem usually becomes obvious!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the term on the left side to be defined, the denominator shouldn't be equal to zero. Therefore $x ≠ 4$.
$$\frac{|2|}{|x-4|} > 1
\\2 > |x-4|
\\|x-4| < 2
\\-2 < x-4 < 2
\\2 < x < 6$$
Hence, the answer is:
$$(2,6) - \{4\}$$

Answer (score 0):

for $$x>4$$ we have $$\frac{2}{x-4}>1$$ therefore we have $$x<6$$
for $$x<4$$ we obtain $$\frac{2}{4-x}>1$$ therefore we get $$x>2$$

Comment: If $x=1$, then $\frac{2}{4-x}=\frac{2}{4-1}=\frac{2}{3}<1$, so your second conclusion is wrong. It should be $x>2$ instead. You can check with $x=3$, $\frac{2}{4-3}=\frac{2}{1}=2>1$, which is correct.

Comment: it just was a typo